# A path object for a non-negatively graded chain complex

Tags: homological-algebra, model-categories

In Mark Hovey's Model categories (chapter 2), a path object of a chain complex is presented. For a chain complex $X$, a chain complex $P$ defined by $P_n := X_n \oplus X_n \oplus X_{n+1}$ is a path object of $X$ (chapter 2, theorem 2.3.11).

But how about the non-negatively graded case?
In the category of non-negatively graded chain complex, path objects should be constructed in a similar fashion but different in 0th degree.

That is, I believe that for a non-negatively graded chain complex $X$, $Q_n:=X_n\oplus X_n\oplus X_{n+1}$ for $n\geq 1$ and $Q_0:=X_1$ will give us a path object. Any proof for this?

Edit:
I realized that $Q\to X$ is not a surjection for the degree $n=0$, so $Q$ is not a path object.

Comment: Do you mean non-negatively graded chain complex, rather than bounded chain complex?

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks, Yes. I edited my post.

Comment: Actually, fibrations in the projective model structure on the category of non-negatively graded chain complexes do not need to be surjective in degree $0$, so that isn't the problem. But your construction is not correct because it has the wrong homology in degree $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a non-negatively graded path object, you can take the "good" truncation of the unbounded path object. The unbounded path object has $Q_{-1} = X_0$ and $Q_0 = X_0 \oplus X_0 \oplus X_1$ with differential $d : Q_0 \to Q_{-1}$ given by $d (x, y, z) = -x + y - d (z)$. The "good" truncation replaces $Q_0$ with $\ker (Q_0 \to Q_{-1})$ so that homology is preserved, so we end up with the submodule of $Q_0$ given by $\{ (x, y, z) : d (z) = y - x \}$, which is easily seen to be isomorphic to $X_0 \oplus X_1$.